# I need one clarification for this: $5^{(x^{2})} =2^{x} \cdot e^{(2x)}$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I solved this equation by giving it these 2 [solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YLWV.png)
Now the system says I am partially correct and gives me this [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwrch.png) instead. Can someone please explain why I am not fully correct on my answer?

Comment: Is it $$5^{x^2}-2^x\times e^{2x}$$?

Comment: What equation?  Where is the = sign?

Comment: I assume you are looking for zeroes of that function...is that correct?

Comment: With obvious notation you have $ax^2=bx+2x$ so $x=0$ and $x=\dfrac{b+2}{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to solve $5^{(x^2)}-2^xe^{2x}=0$, that is
\begin{align*}
5^{(x^2)}-2^xe^{2x}&=0\\
5^{(x^2)}&=2^xe^{2x}\\
\log\left(5^{(x^2)}\right)&=\log\left(2^xe^{2x}\right)\\
x^2\log\left(5\right)&=\log\left(2^x\right)+\log\left(e^{2x}\right)\\
x^2\log\left(5\right)&=x\log(2)+2x\log(e)\\
x^2\log\left(5\right)&=x\log(2)+2x\\
x^2\log\left(5\right)-x\log(2)-2x&=0\\
x\left(x\log\left(5\right)-\log(2)-2\right)&=0\\
\end{align*}
so $x=0$ or $x=\dfrac{\log(2)+2}{\log(5)}$.

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%5E%28x%5E2%29%3D2%5Exe%5E%282x%29) agrees with me, so it seems both your original answer and the proposed one are wrong.